# Read and authentication using network credentials in a generic handler (ashx)

Tags: c#, ashx, generic-handler, networkcredentials

I have created a generic handler inside an entity framework application that displays data from a table. I want to secure the handler in case anyone tries to access it directly with the url or otherwise. Where and how do I write the username and password that authenticates before processing and bringing up the data when this is called from another application (the calling application will have the username and pwd)

```
 public class MyDatahandler: IHttpHandler
{


    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        Mydatalogic a = new dataLogic;
        a.DisplayView();

    }
```

}

The calling request is using 
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
where have mutual agreement of what username and password to use. Where will I map these in my handler?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). This allows you to use role based permissions to access your classes and methods for

Here are some additional attributes that can help lock down your pages:

```
[HttpPost] //URL Post method only

[HttpGet] //URL Post method only

[ChildActionOnly] //Not accessible via URL
```

**EDIT**

You want to secure the handler in case anyone tries to access it directly with the url, right? To do this, check the server variable `HTTP_REFERER` from within MyDatahandler_ProcessRequest. If the user isn't coming from where they should be, throw an HTTP 403 error.

In your web.config, try adjusting it to:

```
<authorization>
    <allow verbs="POST" users="*"/>
    <deny verbs="GET" users="*"/> 
</authorization>
```

This will prevent any direct URL access using URL parameters.

Comment: I have this in the webconfig

Comment: I have this in the webconfig
        <location path="Service/Process.ashx">
          <system.web>
            <authorization>
              <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
         </system.web>
      </location>
But not sure what else to do within the handler. But how does the calling function access using network credentials. I am sure I am missing something